# How do I use trained word2vec model for paragraph2vec in deep4j?

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I want to train my word2vec model on 5 million sentences dataset and use that in my paragraph2vec. Does following suffice my requirement? I am using deep4j word2vec and paragraph2vec implementations

-Train word2vec by building and calling .fit() method

-build a paragraph2vec model by setting vocabCache() as one that I get by word2vec.getVocab() (of trained model of previous step)

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Please join our developer community on Gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j